# Print filename of image in dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, opencv

```
import cv2 as cv
import glob
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
import pandas as pd
from colormath.color_objects import sRGBColor, xyYColor, LabColor, XYZColor
from colormath.color_conversions import convert_color
import xlsxwriter
import os


path = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Color/Fontane/36/*.jpg"
img_number = 1

for file in glob.glob(path):
    print(file)
    img = cv.imread(file)
    scale_percent = 60
    width = int(img.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
    height = int(img.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
    dim = (width, height)
    imgr = cv.resize(img, dim, interpolation=cv.INTER_AREA)

    hsv = cv.cvtColor(imgr, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    blur0 = cv.medianBlur(hsv, 11)

    low_yellow = np.array([17, 25, 210])
    high_yellow = np.array([30, 255, 255])

    mask = cv.inRange(blur0, low_yellow, high_yellow)
    res = cv.bitwise_and(imgr, imgr, mask=mask)

    fname = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0]

    cv.imwrite(f'C:/Users/User/Desktop/Color/Fontane/36/SEG/{fname}.jpg',res)

path1 = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Color/Fontane/36/SEG/*.jpg"
img_number = 1

result_df = pd.DataFrame()
for file in glob.glob(path1):
    image = io.imread(file)
    x = image[np.all(image != 0, axis=2)].mean(axis=0)
    result_df = pd.concat((result_df, pd.DataFrame(x)), axis=1)
    df_t = result_df.T
    fname = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0]
    df_t['name'] = fname
    df_t.columns = ['R', 'G', 'B', 'Filename']
    df_t.loc['Mean'] = df_t.mean()
    df_t = df_t.round(decimals=1)



    writer = pd.ExcelWriter("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Color/Fontane/RGB/36.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter')

    df_t.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='RGB')
   

    writer.save()
```

This code provides me the mean RGB value of a segmentated image. I write those values into a dataframe in Excel. Since I discover the first value in this dataframe does not always match with the first image in my folder I try to print the filename of every image in the excelsheet. . I did some experiments, but as you can see: the printed filename is in each cell the same. It looks like it is overwriting itself.

[image]

I have no idea how to fix this, anyone any ideas?

thank you in advance

Comment: I think you should add file name to the dataframe.
df_t.columns = ['filename','R', 'G', 'B']

Comment: It gives me the following error: Traceback (most recent call last):
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 3 elements, new values have 4 elements

This only ad a column name and doesn't print the filenames in this column

Comment: is that the problem of  Mean row ?   i think the problem would be there is no mean for filename